# List of variable contents with linux echo command Run with qtProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, qprocess

I want to do the "echo" command, which is used to show the variable content in the linux terminal, using the GUI.
I wrote this using qProcess, but it only printed $SHELL as output.

```
QString cmd = "echo $SHELL";
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start(cmd);
process->waitForBytesWritten();
process->waitForFinished();
qDebug() << process->readAll();`
```

Qt code output:$SHELL
........................................

Terminal command:
[intern2atlas SETUP]$ echo $SHELL

output:/bin/tcsh

Comment: Pls ask question properly. Do not add only code.

Comment: thank you, I edited question

Comment: This will help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701504/command-working-in-terminal-but-not-via-qprocess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a example of code. Pls try with this:

```
   env.insert("TERM", "xterm");
    processo.setProcessEnvironment(env);

    //comando 1 - limpar a pasta
    comando = "echo";
    args.clear();
    args<<"$TERM";
    fullCommand = comando;
    for(int i = 0; i < args.count(); i++)
        fullCommand += " " + args.at(i);
    processo.start(comando,args,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    processo.waitForFinished();
    stdOut = processo.readAllStandardOutput();
    stdError = processo.readAllStandardError();
    ui->commandTextEdit->append(fullCommand);
    ui->stdOutTextEdit->append(stdOut);
    ui->stdErrorTextEdit->append(stdError);
```

Refer: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/58131-Execute-system-command-from-QProcess

Answer (score 0):

use `QProcessEnvironment` or `qgetenv` or similar to access environment variables. If what you want to do really needs to invoke a shell, pass that process first (e.g. `sh`). Neither `echo` nor QProcess are a shell and thus won't interpret the environment variable `$SHELL` for you.